# Wizad like control in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I am newbie to xamarin.form where I have to include following control as bellow something like wizard to get collection of steps from user to do a operation.
[image]

In xamarin forms are there anything like this as out of the box ? if so what it is ? if there is not such a thing how to start to build it ?

When I google that 
[System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard/) 
say it has something like this but I could not understand how to integrate with it.does it possible to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

That looks a lot like a carouselview with indicators, if you don't know how to add indicators to a carouselview: http://chrisriesgo.com/xamarin-forms-carousel-view-recipe/ here is a guide.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Frame:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame x:Name="Step001">
        <Label Text="My Stuff" />
    </Frame>
    <Frame x:Name="Step002">
        <Label Text="My Stuff" />
    </Frame>    
</StackLayout>

private void setupStep001(bool isVisibleStep){
    Step001.IsVisible = isVisibleStep;
    Step002.IsVisible = !isVisibleStep;
}
```